# Redirect localhost url in node.js and express

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

i have a project where users connect to my router, and then enter the address `http://192.168.1.50:9091` into the address bar to connect to a page. I would like there to be a way to enter something easier than this long ip address.

here is what's happening so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , fs = require('fs')

server.listen(9093);

var nRequest = 0;
var nConnexs = 0;


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client_app.html');
});

app.get('/2', function (req, res) {   res.sendfile(__dirname +
'/client_app2.html'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by:

> i have a project where users connect to my router

The Node.js application is sitting on your machine. Until somebody accesses your machine (through IP), the application is never accessed.

As such, you must put something between the user and the application that will direct the user to the IP. For real websites, this is accomplished using DNS. You register a domain name and tell the DNS service the IP of the machine to redirect to.

If you have control over the router (internal network, etc.), you can map an alias to your IP address. It all depends on whether your router runs a DNS server or supports DNSMasq. You will need to check your router manufacturer/model/etc.

Finally, if there are a small number of users that will be accessing your website, you could always have them use the `hosts` file to map a name to the IP. The location of this file is dependent upon the operating system; just Google: `edit hosts file`

Answer (score 1):

I assume users are initially connecting to your router's public ip address or a DNS representation of that.  If that's the case, you can usually configure your router to do port forwarding such that incoming requests on a particular port are automatically routed to a particular private IP address on your network.  In that case, the users would connect to your router, but that request would be automatically forwarded to your internal node server and thus the users would end up directly connected to your node server.

This type of configuration comes with the usual security warnings.  Doing this means that your node server must be properly configured against internet attack and your node app must be written with appropriately security precautions - particularly because any compromise to the computer the node server is running on has access to your internal network.

If you show us what users are initially connecting to when they connect to your router, we could offer a more explicit example of how you could configure the router to take advantage of port forwarding.